# Extracting all functions listed in Elementary Introduction to Wolfram Language

Tags: functions

I was trying to find all the Mathematica functions listed in [the index of the Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/book-index.html).

I just cut and pasted everything to a text file and then strung together the ugliest nested Select statement I could based on predicates I found by searching:

```
f = Import["/Users/joe/Documents/z school/mma elementary index.txt"];
firstLetterCapital[x_] := First[ToCharacterCode[x]] < 91
fStringSplitAtSpace = StringSplit[f];
fWordsOnly = Select[
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Select[
    Select[fStringSplitAtSpace, DictionaryWordQ], 
    StringStartsQ[LetterCharacter]
    ]
   ]
  , firstLetterCapital]
```

I'm not winning any prizes for the above but it kinda-mostly works.

My question: is there a straight forward way to find the intersection of the Global rule base(?) with this list? or string yet another Select function with a say, WolframFunctionNameQ predicate?

Of course, more elegant methods of getting there would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more rigours way to get function names is to examine the html elements. Here I assumed the **bold** text of functions are intended functions, so things like `Alignment` is not included.

```
data = Import["https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/book-index.html", "Source"];
Intersection[
 DeleteDuplicates[
  StringCases[data, 
   "<span class=\"FunctionName\">" ~~ Shortest[fun__] ~~ "</span>" :> 
    fun]], Names["System`*"]]
```

Comment: thanks - with my xp level, this answer makes sense.  also, that garden path that i went down set me up to think that it _should_ be a simple Intersection question so your answer was a perfect moment for me to learn about Names.  I have no idea what MB1965 is doing...

Comment: @Joe more or less this but I applied a `StringCases` to pull a more compact set of function names so that we don't get anything that's in the headers or footers of the page. I used `Cases` instead of `Intersection`.

Comment: @happyfish bizarre I get `Abs` fine. Did you have `text =
  Import["https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/book-index.html"];`? I forgot to include that line it seems. Also sans duplicates I have 594.

Comment: @happyfish interestingly your method returns 642 unique functions. I wonder how many of those are ones my rather-string `StringCases` missed and how many come from the header and footer and things. I'm betting most are in the former set.

Comment: @happyfish I think you should stick a `StringTrim[__, Except[("$"|WordCharacter)]..]` in your code. I applied some `StringCases` to drop the footer and header and with that plus the string trim I get some 647 functions (vs 636 without the trim). And using a cleaner (I think) version of my code I get 597 there.

Comment: @happyfish Cute. But in general you'll be better served via `Import[___,{"HTML","XMLObject"}]` and then applying `Cases` on the imported `XMLElements`. Cleaner than parsing HTML I find.

Comment: @happyfish One last thing before Kuba comes in here and grouses about the extended discussion: It seems about 2/3 of what your method pulled by mine didn't was worth having and 1/3 came from things like `"White House"`.

Comment: @happyfish I gave an example of what I mean as an add-on to my answer

Comment: @MB1965 thanks. I will remove those comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be better served by taking the data you can find from [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html):

```
rawText = 
  Import["https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/book-index.html"];
text =
  StringSplit[
    StringCases[rawText, "Index" ~~ Whitespace ~~ "\n" ~~ __][[1]],
    "\n\n"
    ][[1]];
StringCases[
    StringSplit[
     text,
     "\n"
     ],
    (func : (("$" | "") ~~ WordCharacter ..) ~~ ___ ~~ NumberString) :> 
     func
    ] // Flatten // Cases[Alternatives @@ Names["System`*"]] // Sort
```

I get about 597 unique functions from that.

---

Mentioned this in a comment to happyfish but rather than parsing the HTML it is often nicer to use an `XMLObject` representation:

```
xml = Import[
   "https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/book-index.html", {"HTML", "XMLObject"}
   ];

Intersection[
  Cases[
     xml,
     XMLElement[_, {___, "class" -> "FunctionName", ___}, f_] :> f,
     \[Infinity]
     ] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates,
  Names["System`*"]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
url = "https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/book-index.html";
xmlElements[url_] := Import[url, "XMLObject"];
functionElements[xes_] := Position[xes, XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "FunctionName"},{_String}]] // Extract[xss, #] &
systemFunctionNames[xss_] := Map[#[[3]] &, xss] // Union // Flatten // Intersection[#,Names["System`*"]] &
importSystemFunctionNames[url_] := Composition[systemFunctionNames, functionElements, xmlElements][url]
importSystemFunctionNames[url]
```